Fiber over a prime ideal calculation
Suppose we have a ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}[y] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ given by $y \mapsto x^2$. I want to calculate the fibers over the primes (0) and $(y^2 +1)$.
I already know that when for any rings $A$ and $B$, we have a homomorphism $\phi: A \longrightarrow B$ and the induced map $\phi^*: \operatorname{Spec} B\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$, and the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, the fiber of $\phi^*$ over $\mathfrak{p}$ is given by $\operatorname{Spec}(B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}})$ where the localization is considered by taking $B$ as an $A-$module. You could consider your favorite tensor product definition here and it would end up being the same.
So now for prime $\mathfrak{p} = (0)$, we have that the only ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which contracts to (0) in $\mathbb{R}[y]$ under the map $\phi$ given in the beginning is (0) itself. So we end up with the fiber being {(0)}.
For prime $\mathfrak{p} = (y^2 +1)$, we have that the ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which contracts to $(y^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{R}[y]$ under the map $\phi$ given in the beginning is $(x^4 +1)$. So we end up with the fiber being the Spec of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4 +1) \cong \mathbb{C}$ localized at $(y^2+1)$.
Is my answer correct? And is there any way it can be improved? I really am not confident with how everything looks.

The calculation of the fiber at $(0)$ is correct, but you don't prove it. You need to prove that $(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}[y]$ is the only prime ideal that contracts to $(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$. The calculation of the fiber at $(y^2+1)$ is not correct. Again, you don't provide proves. The fiber has actually two points.
It is a bit easier to replace $\phi$ with the canonical morphism $\psi : \mathbb{R}[y] \to \mathbb{R}[y][x]/(x^2-y)$.
The fiber of a ring homomorphism $\psi : A \to B$ at $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is isomorphic to the spectrum of the ring $B \otimes_A Q(A/\mathfrak{p})$.
In our case this is
$$\mathbb{R}[y][x]/(x^2-y) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}[y]} Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p}) \cong Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})[x]/(x^2-y)$$
The structure of this ring depends on how the polynomial $x^2-y$ decomposes over the field $Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})$. If $y$ has a root $\sqrt{y} \in Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})$, then the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us
$${\small Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})[x]/(x^2-y) \cong Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})[x]/(x-\sqrt{y}) \times Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})[x]/(x+\sqrt{y}) \cong Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})^2},$$
at least when $y \neq 0$ (so that the roots are distinct). This is a product of two fields, hence it has exactly two prime ideals. If however $y=0$ in $Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})$, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}=(y)$, we get $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$, which also has exactly one prime ideal, but the fiber, as a scheme, is not reduced.
If however $y$ does not have a root in $Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p})$, the polynomial $x^2-y$ is irreducible, so that the quotient is just a field, having exactly one prime ideal.
For $\mathfrak{p}=0$ we have $Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p}) = \mathbb{R}(y)$, and clearly $y$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{R}(y)$ (Eisenstein's Criterion). This means the fiber has exactly one point.
For $\mathfrak{p}=(y^2+1)$ we have $Q(\mathbb{R}[y]/\mathfrak{p}) = \mathbb{C}$ with $ y=i$, and $i$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$, namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1+i)$. It follows that the fiber has exactly two points. The two corresponding prime ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are $(x \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1+x^2))$.
